# WP_Query args order-by ignored

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Seen similar questions posted, but no answers yet...
I have set the args for a WP_Query to:

```
function get_url_shortcode($atts, $content =null) {
    $query_args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'order_by' => 'title',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'tax_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $atts[cat1],
            ),
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $atts[cat2]
            )
        ),
        'post_type' => 'product'
    );  
    remove_all_filters('posts_orderby');
    $loop = new WP_Query($query_args);
    var_dump($loop->request);
}
```

This shortcode function does produce the correct results, but the OrderBy of Title, which I have set in the args, is not only ignored, but when I dump the generated Select, it appears that the OrderBy is set to Post_Date ASC.

```
string(567) "SELECT wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id) INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships AS tt1 ON (wp_posts.ID = tt1.object_id) WHERE 1=1 AND ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (1554,9907,9908,9909,9910,9911,9912) AND tt1.term_taxonomy_id IN (357,1555,1556,1557,1559,1560,1561,1562,1570,1571,1572,1573,1644,6309,7903) ) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'product' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private') GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date ASC "
```

I have shut off all plugins and reverted to a default theme TwentySixteen and get the same results. This is happening elsewhere in the code, too, as other lists (***not*** generated using this shortcode function) are not being ordered correctly, either. So I do not think it is my code specifically, but somewhere something is overwriting my query and I don't know where or how to track it down.

Any ideas?
Thanks,
Rich

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no underscore in `orderby`:

```
'orderby' => 'title',
```

More info [in the Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters).